Seaborn--How to fix black line on seaborn barplot
I used the code below for a barplot but I am getting these black line on the chart. What's causing these lines and how can I remove them? Also. See below.
plt.figure(figsize=(14, 10))
sns.set(rc={    
    "xtick.labelsize": 15,   
    "ytick.labelsize": 15    
})
sns.barplot(x='Industry', y='Revenue', data=df, hue='Industry', palette='viridis')

plt.title('Total Revenue by Industry')
plt.ylabel('Revenue (in $ millions)')
plt.xticks(rotation=70)



can you provide example image. I think you meant to do that but you ended up just keeping the Markdown annotation instead.

First, you need to clarify what you want. You are providing multiple y-values per bar.  By default, seaborn will take their mean, and indicate the confidence with an error bar.  Use errorbar=None to suppress the error bar. If you want to use the sum of the y-values (instead of their mean), you can use estimator="sum", errorbar=None). See the barplot docs
